# More elegant way to filter out table rows using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, tablefilter

I would like to make my table filter more elegant. Basically, this table will have links at the bottom to hide and show rows based on attributes in the table. It's working the way I want, but I feel like I could have written using a lot fewer lines of jQuery... Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vC88q/1/

And the code:

```
<!--*******************************************************
jquery that needs cleaned up appears at the end of this file!
Code is online at JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vC88q/1/
*********************************************************-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Color Table</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="red">red</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="white">white</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="blue">blue</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="bluewhite">bluewhite</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="red">red</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="red">red</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="red">red</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="blue">blue</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td data-color="blue">blue</td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table> 
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="filtertable">
        <a href="#" data-color="all">All</a>
        <a href="#" data-color="red">Red</a>
        <a href="#" data-color="white">White</a>
        <a href="#" data-color="blue">Blue</a>
        <a href="#" data-color="bluewhite">Blue and White</a>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*******************************************************
Here is the jquery I need help with, how can I reduce the code
I've written? Code is online at JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vC88q/1/
*********************************************************/

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
    /*****************************************************************
    when users clicks the "all" filter, show all the hidden table rows
    *****************************************************************/
    $('.filtertable a[data-color=all]').click(function() {
        $('td[data-color]').parent().show();
    });
    /****************************************************************
    when users clicks the "red" filter, hide all but red table rows
    *****************************************************************/
    $('.filtertable a[data-color=red]').click(function() {
        $('td[data-color=red]').parent().show();
        $('td[data-color=white]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=blue]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=bluewhite]').parent().hide();
    });
    /*****************************************************************
    when users clicks the "white" filter, hide all but white table rows
    ****************************************************************/
    $('.filtertable a[data-color=white]').click(function() {
        $('td[data-color=white]').parent().show();
        $('td[data-color=red]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=blue]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=bluewhite]').parent().hide();
    });
    /****************************************************************
    when users clicks the "blue" filter, hide all but blue table rows
    *****************************************************************/
    $('.filtertable a[data-color=blue]').click(function() {
        $('td[data-color=blue]').parent().show();
        $('td[data-color=white]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=red]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=bluewhite]').parent().hide();
    });
    /*****************************************************************
    when users clicks the "blue and white" filter, hide all but blue+white table rows
    *****************************************************************/
    $('.filtertable a[data-color=bluewhite]').click(function() {
        $('td[data-color=bluewhite]').parent().show();
        $('td[data-color=white]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=blue]').parent().hide();
        $('td[data-color=red]').parent().hide();
    });
} 
); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.filtertable a[data-color]').click(function() {
            var color = $(this).data().color;
            if(color == 'all'){
                 $('td[data-color]').parent().show();
            } else {
                $('td[data-color='+ color +']').parent().show();
                $('td[data-color!='+color+']').parent().hide();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Awesome. This is very clean and works for all the configurations. Thanks for the fast replies everyone. I wish I could have picked several answers as correct!

Comment: Hey, can you translate this variable into english for me?  var color = $(this).data().color; ah, i just realized .data is a way of accessing the data-color attribute... thanks!

Comment: Want to pick several answers?  That's what the upvote is for.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vC88q/8/)

```
$(function() {
    var td = $('#colortable td');
    $('.filtertable').on('click', 'a', function() {
        var color = this.getAttribute('data-color');
        if (color === 'all') {
            td.parent().show()
        } else {
            td.filter('[data-color=' + color + ']').parent().show()
            td.filter('[data-color!=' + color + ']').parent().hide()
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

I frequently use CSS for this sort of thing.

```
<table id="myTable" class="all">
  <tr class="red"><td>red</td></tr>
  <tr class="yellow"><td>yellow</td></tr>
  <tr class="blue"><td>blue</td></tr>
<table>

<div class="controls">
  <a href="#" data-color="all">All</a>
  <a href="#" data-color="red">Red</a>
  <a href="#" data-color="white">White</a>
  <a href="#" data-color="blue">Blue</a>
</div>
```

And then in JS

```
$('.controls a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var c= $(this).data('color');
  $('#myTable')[0].className = c;
});​
```

The CSS determines what shows when:

```
tr { display: none; }
.all tr { display: table-row; }
.red tr.red { display: table-row; }
.blue tr.blue { display: table-row; }
.yellow tr.yellow { display: table-row; }
```

In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4QKT/).

Comment: Awesome answer. I'm going to explore this more... It's by far the shortest bit of JS to accomplish what I wanted to do...

Answer (score 1):

The following should replace all your code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filtertable a[data-color]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this), color = $this.data('color');
        if (color !== 'all') {
            $('td[data-color]').parent().hide();
        }
        $('td[data-color' + (color !== 'all' ? '=' + color : '') + ']').parent().show();
    });
});​
```

EDIT: Updated to fix 'All' link

Comment: You're fast :) That works for the colors, but now the "all" option does not work for some reason... Even when I leave the code for the "all" option untouched.

Comment: @Fred I fixed it so it works now. :-) I overlooked the 'all' option the first time.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/vC88q/6/

```
    $('.filtertable a[data-color]').click(function() {
        var color = $(this).data().color;
        $('td[data-color=' + color + ']').parent().show();
        $('td[data-color!=' + color + ']').parent().hide();
    });
```

Comment: I ran into an issue with the "all" button no longer working when I tried this... I think I see now, I just needed an if/else to handle that, then I needed to focus on the colors.